# Show that the quotient is homeomorphic to the Möbius band

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ act on $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ by exchanging the coordinates. Show that the quotient is homeomorphic to the Möbius band. (Hint: Start with finding a nice polygonal representation for the quotient, then proceed with the polygonal representation Voodoo).

Studying for an exam so going through an old homework. This is the problem we got from our teacher.

Ok so we have a group action on a product space and I want to show that the quotient is homeomorphic to the Möbius band. I know the polygonal presentation for the Möbius band: $<a,b,c|abcb>$. I also know that the Möbius band is homeomorphic to the projective plane deleting an 2-cell. But I dont really know how to get from here?